# Passing Multiple Files in SED Command: Log Extract

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I am trying to extract logs from my application within specific time-stamps. So i wrote the following script

```
a= echo $1 | sed 's/\//\\\//g';
b= echo $2 | sed 's/\//\\\//g';

sed -n "/$a/,/$b/p" $3;
```

Here $1 and $2 are the timestamps within which i want the logs and $3 is the file from where i want it.

This script works perfect if i pass a single file. But if i multiple files or a directory as parameters it does not give any output.

This is how i am executing the script

```
extract.sh '6/30/14 9:03' '6/30/14 9:05' abc_*/SysOut.log
```

Can SED work with multiple files or the issue is with UNIX with its limitation in passing files as parameters

Any suggesstion of help in this regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sed command should be

```
sed -n "/$a/,/$b/p" -- "${@:3}"
```

Note if you're not using Bash, you can shift those arguments first before running sed:

```
shift 2
sed -n "/$a/,/$b/p" -- "$@"
```